Continuity of Electric Potential in the Vicinity of a Charged soap bubble
This is not completely a homework question, I have relatively deeper questions at the end.

My Solution:
I assumed that say, a charge Q is distributed over the bubble and thus the electric potential energy of the bubble before the perturbation turns out to be,
$$U_E=\int_0^Q \frac{kQdq}{r}=\frac{kQ^2}{r}$$
Similarly the surface energy turns out to be,
$$U_S=2(4\pi r^2)\sigma$$
Next, to find out the forces, I took the negative gradients of both these energies (I'm choosing a radially outward direction to be the positive one),
$$F_E=-\frac{dU_E}{dr}=\frac{kQ^2}{r^2}
\\F_S=-\frac{dU_S}{dr}=-16\sigma\pi r$$
Since at equilibrium, the net force is zero, we get,
$$\boxed{16\sigma\pi r_{eq}=\frac{kQ^2}{r_{eq}^2}}$$
Now, since the amplitude is very small when compared to the radius, we may write the small net restoring force that appears after the perturbation (from the 'equilibrium radius') as,
$$F_{res}=dF_S+dF_E=-16\sigma\pi dr-\frac{2kQ^2}{r_{eq}^3}dr\\F_{res}=-48\sigma\pi dr$$
Then solving for time period using the SHM definition with dr being substituted for amplitude yields,
$$T=\sqrt{\frac{\pi m}{12\sigma}}$$
Which is actually the right answer. My professor wasn't fully convinced with my approach. He told that my approach was too simplistic and the real solution involved electric field energy density and a bit of vector calculus but I feel that my solution is completely right.
Can I always use a potential energy-gradient based approach to derive forces or are there any pitfalls e.g. cases where the gradient is a discontinuous function?
My professor argues that it was wrong to manipulate a discontinuous function as the electric force vanishes just inside the bubble, though I don't feel odd since the potential energy is completely continuous and differentiable in this case.
Is my approach really right or is it a mere coincidence that I ended up with the right answer?
Edit: What does it mean to say that the potential in this case is a function of the radius but not a function of position? Aren't both the same?
[Image and problem source : Pathfinder for Olympiads and JEE Advanced Physics by Pearson Publications]

The problem with your solution
The problem is that your electric potential is wrong. The way you calculated it is vague, and to get the correct expression we should be more careful.
If you have a discrete distribution of charges $q_1,\dots,q_N$, the total electric potential over the charge $q_i$ will be
$$
U_i = \sum_{j\neq i} {kq_iq_j\over r_{ij}}
$$
To get the total electric potential of the distribution, we should sum over $i$
$$
U = \sum_i \sum_{j\leq i} V_i = \frac 12 \sum_i \sum_{j\neq i} {kq_iq_j\over r_{ij}}
$$
For a continuum distribution, we have
$$
U = \frac 12 \int_V \int_V k{\rho(\vec r)\rho(\vec r')\over |\vec r-\vec r'|} d\vec r d\vec r' \equiv \frac 12 \int_V \rho(\vec r)V(\vec r) d\vec r 
$$
In the case, we only have superficial charges over the bubble, so the charge density in this expression should be substituted by a superficial density charge, and the integration over the surface, which gives
$$
U =\frac 12 \int_S \lambda (\vec r) V(\vec r) dS = \frac 12 {kQ\over R} \int_S \lambda dS = {kQ^2\over 2R}
$$
Note two things:

This expression differs from your expression by a factor of $\frac 12$. This factor arises when we sum over all element of charges and should be there, otherwise we would be summing up twice the same contributions.
This is not a function of position. Since we already integrated, this is a fixed quantity or, if you want, a function of the radius $R$, but then it is a continuous and differentiable function of $R$.

As you thought, the negative radial derivative of this potential gives a force that points outward)
$$
F_{el}^0 = - {dU\over dR} = {kQ^2\over 2R^2}
$$
and in equilibrium, this force balance the tension of the bubble.
You found the right result with the wrong electric potential energy, because in the end the equilibrium condition eliminate any constant multiplying the electric potential (note that the period is independent of $k$, for example).
Discontinuity of the gradient
As I said above, the function $U$ is not discontinuous in the variable $R$, but this variable is not a position variable, but the radius of the bubble. If we back to the expression
$$
U =\frac 12 \int_V \rho (\vec r) V(\vec r) dV
$$
We can use the Gauss law $\nabla \cdot \vec E = 4\pi k \rho$ to write (after some manipulations with vector calculus)
$$
U = \frac{1}{8\pi k} \int_V |\vec E|^2 dV \rightarrow u(r) = \frac{1}{8\pi k} E(r)^2
$$
The function $u(r)$ is the electric energy density and it is a function of position, since we should integrate it to get $U$. The electric field is discontinuous, and also the energy density
$$
u(r) = 
\begin{cases}
0, \quad  r< R\\
{kQ^2\over 8\pi r^4}, \quad r\geq R.
\end{cases} 
$$
You could check that it gives $U$ by integrating over the whole space. This function is discontinuous and could not be derivated. What we could say is that this function could be used to calculate the energy decrease if an element $\delta S$ of the surface to be displaced $\delta r$:
$$
W = - u \delta S \delta r = - {kQ^2\over 8\pi R^4} \delta S \delta r
$$
So we could say that there is an outward force per unit of area given by $kQ^2/8\pi R^4$. You could think that this result is different from the previous one, but it's just that if you multiply this force by $4\pi R^2$ you get the same force derived previously. I'll not give more details of this path, but you should try solving this way.

I think your professor was expecting you to deal with the energy density, not the integrated version, but after integration this function is not discontinuous. You calculated the electric potential by strange ways and your result is wrong by a factor, but this factor does not affect the final result, because we impose equilibrium.

Really thanks for your help! Actually, after posting the question, I realised that my electric potential energy might be wrong up to constant and sure enough, it is. Anyways, I'm pleased to know that my solution is correct, elsewise!
